# Google Sheets importxml query to remove one piece of data

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the following query in my sheet to import total Spotify streams for artists.  Example:

`=IMPORTXML("https://chartmasters.org/spotify-streaming-numbers-tool/?artist_name=&artist_id=1uh2pZRWuOebEoQgFVKK7l&displayView=Disco","//tr[@class='careerTotals'][2]")`

However it's returning one extra value I don't want ("EAS").  I would like to just have the artist name in A and the total streams in B.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about these modifications?

#### Modified formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[@class='careerTotals'][2]/td[position()<3]"))
```

or

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[@class='careerTotals'][2]"),"SELECT Col1,Col2")
```

- The URL of `https://chartmasters.org/spotify-streaming-numbers-tool/?artist_name=&artist_id=1uh2pZRWuOebEoQgFVKK7l&displayView=Disco` is put in the cell "A1".
- At 1st modified script, the expected values are retrieved with xpath of `//tr[@class='careerTotals'][2]/td[position()<3]` and those are put to the columns using `TRANSPOSE`.
- At 2nd modified script, the expected values are retrieved from the retrieved 3 values using `QUERY`.

#### Result:

This result is from the 1st modified formula. 2nd one is also the same result.

[image]

#### References:

- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts.  Perfect!

Comment: @owenw Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.